# Using Items definition on public static void in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have problem using `Items` on `public static void`.

When I try to recover with a `for each` the items element is not recognized.

How to do resolve this ?

Please, can you help me ?

My code below.

**.aspx**

```
  <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="propo" runat="server"
        UseSelectAllNode="false"
        Enabled="true"
        CssClass="body"
        UseButtons="true">
        <Style SelectBoxWidth="400"
            DropDownBoxBoxWidth="400"
            DropDownBoxBoxHeight="500"
            SelectBoxCssClass="body"
            DropDownBoxCssClass="body" />
        <Texts SelectBoxCaption="[ ------- Select ------- ]" />
    </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

**.cs**

```
public class pnpropo
{
    public string propo { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public static void Savepnpro(pnpropo pro)
{
   string xpro = string.Empty;

   foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in pro.propo.Items) <<< line error
   {
      if (item.Selected)
      {
         xpro += item.Value + "; ";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: property propo of class pnpropo is of type string. Thus it can't have an IEnumerable property Items

Comment: @apomene thanks, but how should I set the property of class pnpropo for  property Items?

Comment: Listbox and ListViewItem controls usually have an Items property

Comment: @apomene any example please ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the type of property `propo`. I suggest you use a

```
List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>
```

Try like:

```
public class pnpropo
{
    public List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem> propo { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public static void Savepnpro(pnpropo pro)
{
   string xpro = string.Empty;

   foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in pro.propo) 
   {
      if (item.Selected)
      {
         xpro += item.Value + "; ";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I have error internal server on `public List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem> propo { get; set; }`